# Let $T:V \rightarrow V$ such that $T^2 = \frac{1}{2}T$. Find its characteristic polynomial.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am used to dealing with transforms such as $T:P_2(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow P_2(\mathbb{R})$ where $T(ax^2 + bx + c) = (a+b)x^2+cx$. In this case you would just use a basis of $P_2(\mathbb{R})$ and create a matrix representation of the transform. But in this case you cannot do that since you don't really have a lot of information about the transformation.

Can this even be done? If so how?

Comment: suppose $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue, can you say something about it using the equation?

Comment: @Phicar If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue then $T(v) = \lambda v$, so $T(T(v)) = T( \lambda v) = \lambda T(v) = \lambda^2 v$. So in this case $\lambda = (1/2)^{1/2}$?

Comment: Not quite, more that $\lambda ^2 v=\frac{\lambda}{2}v.$

Comment: @Phicar Oh I see. From this we just solve for $\lambda$ (if the want the eigenvalues) or rewrite it as $(2 \lambda -1) \lambda$. Thank you

Comment: Note that the $0$ matrix satisfies $T^2 = \frac{1}{2}T$, but its characteristic polynomial is not $(2\lambda-1)\lambda$.  There are other cases, too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $T^2=\frac{1}{2}T$, then $T^2-\frac{1}{2}T = 0$, so polynomial $x^2 - \frac{1}{2}{x}$ divides the characteristic polynomial.  But this is a $2 \times 2$ matrix, so the characteristic polynomial has degree $2$, and thus $x^2 - \frac{1}{2}x$ is the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: Note that this is not right ... according to my comment to the question itself.